# htaccss rewrite url redirect when directory exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2.4

I have this content on my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and on index.php file I have this:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
```

If I visit http://localhost/index.php

I got this. That is OK:

> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(9) "index.php" }

If I visit http://localhost/other

I got: ... It is OK too:

> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(5) "other" }

The problem comes when I try to visit a link with an existent folder name. On other words, If I have a folder called `css`, when I visit http://localhost/css, my url become: `http://localhost/css/?url=css`

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing slash is added in front of existing directories due to security reasons and this is done in a module called `mod_dir` that runs after `mod_rewrite` module. Hence you get query string as well after trailing slash addition.

You can do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: but this adds another problem: if I visit `http://localhost/` then url will become `http://localhost//////////` with infinity redirection error

Comment: Let me test and revert